# Como hacer PING a varias dirección IP con PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema donde puedan ver las diferentes direciones si estan Online o Offline y que se muestre en una cenda de una tabla HTML asi como esta en el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como lo hago? Estoy utilizando **PHP**, aunque si se puede también lo haría en **Javascript**.

tengo este codigo pero solo me toma la primer direcion y no se como hacer que me lo tome en una tabla

```
<?php


class CheckDevice {

        public function myOS(){
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public function ping($ip_addr){
            if ($this->myOS()){
                if (!exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 ".$ip_addr." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
                    return true;
            } else {
                if (!exec("ping -q -c1 ".$ip_addr." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    $ip_addr = array (10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx,"10.49.xx.xx");   


if ((new CheckDevice())->ping($ip_addr))
    echo "HOST ONLINE";
else 
    echo "HOST OFFLINE"
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falta es recorrer el array con las IPs mediante un for y en cada una de las iteraciones llamar al metodo ping de CheckDevice

```
<?php


class CheckDevice {

        public function myOS(){
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public function ping($ip_addr){
            if ($this->myOS()){
                if (!exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 ".$ip_addr." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
                    return true;
            } else {
                if (!exec("ping -q -c1 ".$ip_addr." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    $ip_addr = array ("10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx");   

$checkDevice = new CheckDevice();

for($i = 0; $i < count($ip_addr); $i++){
    if ($checkDevice->ping($ip_addr[$i]))
        echo "HOST ONLINE";
    else 
        echo "HOST OFFLINE"
}

    ?>
```